# Currency textbox react-native

Tags: javascript, mobile, react-native

I'm trying to create a currency input, that starts as something like

```
" $00.00"
```

and then when you start typing, it types the cents first, then moves on to the dollars (ie, updates the right side numbers first), e.g

```
" $00.50"
```

A reddit user posted this piece of JS code to help me : https://codepen.io/benjaminreid/pen/gRbgxK?editors=0010

```
const FormattedInput = class extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.amountChanged = this.amountChanged.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      value: 0,
    };
  }

  amountChanged(e) {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  formatValue(value) {
    return accounting.formatMoney(parseFloat(value) / 100);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label for="formatted">Formatted input</label>
        <input
          id="formatted"
          type="text"
          value={this.formatValue(this.state.value)}  
        />
        <label for="amount">Actual user input (type in here)</label>
        <input
          id="amount"
          type="text"
          onChange={this.amountChanged}
          value={this.state.value}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const App = () =>
  <div>
    <FormattedInput/>
  </div>
;

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

It works great, but the input you enter and the input that gets displayed are in two different boxes. I was wondering if there was a way to type straight into the formatted currency box?

Does anyone have a better solution perhaps? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Difficult, you'd need to apply the format and move the cursor to the correct place on change. Also when saving, you'll need to remove the formatting! Could you style it so the fields look like one, but are actually two? E.g. no borders, view contains them with a background colour and border.

Comment: Won't this still result in having two lines of text show up (the text you type, and the formatted text) ? I find it weird that react-native doesn't have an easy way to handle currency inputs.

Comment: Had the same issue and used similar hack like @G0dsquad suggested. I placed <Text> on top of <TextInput> and setting textinput color to transparent. So it looks like single component. There are libraries out there that handle this but the text keeps flicker when type so I ended up with this workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to code something to solve your problem. It is not so hard to build from scratch.

```
const FormattedInput = class extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.amountChanged = this.amountChanged.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      value: '',
      rawValue: '',
    };
  }

  amountChanged(e) {
    let tmpAmount = '';
    let tmpValue = e.target.value.slice(-1);
    let newRawValue = this.state.rawValue + tmpValue;

    if ( this.state.value.length > e.target.value.length) {
      this.setState({
        value: '',
        rawValue: '',
      })
    }
    else {
      if (newRawValue.length === 1) {
        tmpAmount = '0.0' + newRawValue;
      }
      else if (newRawValue.length === 2) {
        tmpAmount = '0.' + newRawValue;
      }
      else {
        let intAmount = newRawValue.slice(0, newRawValue.length - 2);
        let centAmount = newRawValue.slice(-2);

        tmpAmount = intAmount.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + '.' + centAmount;

      }

      this.setState({
        value: tmpAmount,
        rawValue: newRawValue,
      });

    }
  }

  formatValue(value) {
    return accounting.formatMoney(parseFloat(value) / 100);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label for="amount">Mix</label>
        <input
          id="amount"
          type="text"
          placeholder="$0.00"
          onChange={this.amountChanged}
          value={this.state.value}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const App = () =>
<div>
  <FormattedInput/>
</div>
;

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

Comment: I'm testing your solution, it types number from right to left, however, it always type all digits the same, depends on first digit, for example, if I type 4, it will display 0.04, then I Type 5, and it display 0.44, then I type 6 and it displays as 4.44

Comment: @Lucky_girl I could not reproduce your issue. You can try the solution from that [pen](https://codepen.io/milkers/pen/bmGKQx?editors=0010).